# Secure Browsing Method of Getting Facebook Photos Using APIs

Tags: facebook-graph-api, https, photos

Using the facebook graph you can get photo information as follows:
https://graph.facebook.com/20531316728

However the link they provide to actually grab the photos are not secure and use http:
http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/174597_20531316728_2866555_s.jpg

Replacing http with https doesn't do the trick because you get a security warning:
https://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/174597_20531316728_2866555_s.jpg

Facebook is insisting that all apps use secure browsing and use https. However my app uses facebook photos, which cannot be accessed because they begin with http.

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. You can add a parameter to get a the ssl parameter:

https://graph.facebook.com/20531316728&return_ssl_resources=1

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across a way to ask the API for valid https versions of the images other than for profile pictures.  That is done by `https://graph.facebook.com/{userId/Name}/picture`

Here's Zuck: https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture and https://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the PHP SDK, this was a F***ing life-saver (where $album['cover_photo'] is the id of a photo):

```
$this->facebook->api($album['cover_photo'],'GET',array('return_ssl_resources'=>1));
```

Whenever i would simply add &return_ssl_resources=1 to the end of the query itself my server would throw a 500 error. I found another thread that showed that you can pass this argument in an array.

Comment: And you just had to re-post now what the thread opener already stated in january …?

Comment: Excuse me, but i thought it'd be helpful to provide an example for PHP users as you dont just simply add a url parameter as the original poster suggested, you have to add it as a function parameter. I was NOT reposting, just adding more info and an example of practical use.